# Show that $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$, where for each k, $E_k$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on E that converges to the real valued f pointwise on E. Show that $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$, where for each k, $E_k$ is measurable, and ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each $E_k$ if $k>1$ and $m(E_1)=0$.

I have been stuck in this problem for a while now i do not know where to even begin or what to  look for exactly, if anyone can provide some guidance that will be great

Comment: What are the $E_k$ ?

Comment: @Surb: I think part of the problem is finding such a family of $E_k$.
user146269: have you considered what you'd get if you started by setting $E_k := f_k \cdot \chi_E$?

Comment: Is the measure of $E$ finite or not necessarily ?

Comment: i am guessing the measure of E is finite

Comment: I think that you should start with Lusin's theorem which states that every measurable function is continuous on "most" of its domain.